# Prevent Reflected XSS execution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, xss

I have a Web API method with following signature

```
[RoutePrefix("api/data")]
public class DataController : ApiController
{

 [Route("", Name = "GetData")]
 [HttpGet]
 public HttpResponseMessage GetData(int page= 0, int pageSize = 10, string state = "all")
 {
   // Code to get the data from database
 }
}
```

This method is invoked from the angularjs application:

```
var route = "/data" + "?state=" + state + "&page=" + page + "&pageSize=" + pageSize;
this.$http.get(this.api + route).success(function (response) {
    // Code to get the details
}
```

Now I tried to execute the URL : `http://localhost/api/data?state=open&page=0&pageSize="--></script><svg/onload=';alert(/XSS/);'>` using Firefox browser and I see that an alert dialog box is displayed.

Can anyone provide their guidance to fix this issue

Comment: This looks like a cross-site scripting issue.  Check your urls and see if going from localhost to another host.  This might help: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108835/how-does-cors-prevent-xss

Comment: Here in this case when I am trying to execute the URL using a browser mentioned above it is not hitting the debug point set for the method GetData

Comment: It is not getting to your controller because XSS is preventing you from accessing it.  If you configure CORS, you will probably be able to hit it.

Comment: CORS is already enabled.                                                                              
           // Enable CORS Support
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

Comment: It has nothing to do with cors. Also something somewhere writes that parameter into the page unencoded, but it's not the code you posted. Have a look at where the script is in the page, find out how it got there and encode it. :)

Comment: I am executing the request  directly from the firefox browser itself.

Comment: I get that, but the parameter with the script tag is added to the page DOM, and whatever adds it is not posted in the question. You have to find that, and encode appropriately (or add as a text node) to prevent xss.

Comment: The call to the api is made from the angularjs application directly. Now while testing the service call from the browser directly with malicious script tag I see the issue.